# vb.net add string in the beginning of each line in array of string

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, string, concatenation

i got an array of string extract it from website like this

```
string1.com
string2.com
string3.com
string4.com
string6.com
string7.com
string8.com
.
.
.
stringN.com
```

How to add a string `https://www.`to ech line in that array 
to be like this :

```
https://www.string1.com
https://www.string2.com
https://www.string3.com
https://www.string4.com
https://www.string5.com
https://www.string6.com
https://www.string7.com
.
.
.
.
https://www.stringN.com
```

Comment: 100,000 google hits using your title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a for-loop:

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To MyArray.Length - 1
    MyArray(i) = "https://www." & MyArray(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

And for heck of it, method #3

```
Imports System.Linq
. . . . . . . . 
Dim urls() As String = origArray.Select(Function(o) "https://www." & o).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Linq-based approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx).

```
Dim urls = From s In listOfStrings
           Select "https://www." & s
```